# Firebase Storage - Upload image to firebase storage and create a link to that in realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am having trouble uploading an image to firebase storage. I need to have an input object in the HTML with a type of file. Then I need the image selected for that input to be uploaded to the firebase storage for my project. Is there also a way to store the location of that image in the real-time database so it can be accessed later? How would I do this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes but I'm mainly looking for info on how to upload images easily

Comment: well this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files is the only way. After that you can implement my answer below

Comment: Have a look at this utility class to upload images, videos, and files to Firebase Storage. https://handyopinion.com/utility-class-to-upload-images-videos-files-to-firebase-storage-in-swift-ios/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

to link to the database try this:

```
var ref= firebase.database().ref("Uploads");
var storage = firebase.storage();
var pathReference = storage.ref('images/stars.jpg');
pathReference.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
ref.push().set({
imgurl: url
});
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

after adding it to the storage, you will be able to get the `url` using `getDownloadUrl()` and then add it in the db:

```
Uploads
  pushid
     imgurl: url
```

Comment: I think you meant put(), not push().

Comment: No push() to create a randomid and then set the image under it

Answer (score 5):

Check example application using **Firestore(Storage)** to save image file and using **Cloud Storage(Database)** to save image path, name, and file size.

[image]

**Upload Image**

```
// The main task
this.task = this.storage.upload(path, file, { customMetadata });
```

**Save Image Info**

```
  addImagetoDB(image: MyData) {
    //Create an ID for document
    const id = this.database.createId();

    //Set document id with value in database
    this.imageCollection.doc(id).set(image).then(resp => {
      console.log(resp);
    }).catch(error => {
     console.log("error " + error);
    });
  }
```

**Source tutorial [Link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-image-upload-with-progress-in-firestore-and-firestorage-tutorial-by-application/)**